# Objects looks broken when given cell fracture

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

[image]

I did a rigid body simulation where the objects will be shattered by another by giving cell fracture, but the objects looks broken before it gets smashed. And Also when I render the animation the simulation does not work ?

How to correct it?

Comment: It looks broken but you probably can't avoid that, you need to use a non-broken version before it shatters, while the shattered is invisible, then do the opposite, make the shattered pieces visible and the non-broken invisible. As for the render, maybe bake before rendering? Or please share your file so that we can test it: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: because you fractured it. now it's destroyed.. it's like dropping a glass and putting the broken pieces together, it will always be visible. so do the workaround as mentioned by moonboots. you can easily disable/enable animate the render icon within the Outliner.

Comment: You probably *can* avoid it looking broken; the likely reason here is that you've changed smooth shaded normals by cell fracturing it, and you can copy normals from an unbroken version if you want.  But there is a potential that other material parameters are involved in this as well.  A file would make that clear.  As for difference in render/preview, make sure you bake the physics, and check for any modifiers with different render/preview settings, and any objects hidden in viewports but not renders.

Comment: Thank you so much